# Does Xpath to find web element in Selenium use single quote or double quote to wrap the value?

Tags: selenium, xpath

I m wondering, does Xpath use `'` or `"` for the value ?

I have this web element that I want to grab

`<div class="has-error ng-scope ng-hide" ng-show="element['ServerValidationFailed']">Sorry, that isn't a valid number.</div>`

Normally Xpath should have this pattern `Xpath=//tagname[@attribute='value']`

But when I tried using `'` to surround the value like these

`//div[@ng-show='element['ServerValidationFailed']']`   and
`//div[text()='Sorry, that isn't a valid number.']` ,

these don't work (Google Chrome Developer Tool won't find the web element).

When I tried `"` for the value like these

`//div[@ng-show="element['ServerValidationFailed']"]`  and

`//div[text()="Sorry, that isn't a valid number."]`

It works fine (Chrome Developer tool will find a match).

I am a bit confused now, should it be single quote `'` or double quote `"` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Either one works fine. It comes down to the content you want to match against.

Examples shown in [w3.org xpath abbreviated syntax](https://www.w3.org/TR/2017/REC-xpath-31-20170321/#abbrev) suggests double quotes (`"`).

The reason is because you can escape `"` with `\"` but you cannot escape `'` with `\'`.

If the value you want to match contains `'` character, you should use `"` to wrap the value.

```
//div[@ng-show="element['ServerValidationFailed']"]
```

---

If the value you want to match contains `"` but not `'`, you can use `'` to wrap the value.

```
//div[@ng-show='element["ServerValidationFailed"]']
```

---

If the value you want to match contains both `"` & `'`, you have to use `"` to wrap the value and escape your `"` in your value with `\"`.

```
//div[@ng-show="element['ServerValidationFailed']==\"0\""]
```

This will match something like

```
<div ng-show="element['ServerValidationFailed']==&quot;0&quot;"></div>
```

Not saying you should do this but just in case if you need it.

Comment: Thanks for that. Out of curiosity, `//div[@ng-show="element['ServerValidationFailed']==\"0\""]` will find `<div ng-show="element['ServerValidationFailed']==&quot;0&quot;"></div>` , what does `\"0\"` mean? Does `\"0\"` represent `&quot;0&quot;` ? Can't we just use `//div[@ng-show="element['ServerValidationFailed']==&quot;0&quot;"]` ?  Thanks.

Comment: @keylogger In HTML, `&quot;` gets translated into `"`. [See example](https://codepen.io/josephting/pen/rbxyBg)

Answer (score 3):

The xpath supports both single and double quotes for defining the attributes, but in case of single quote escaping it doesn't follow the general programming concept. So in case of single quote escaping always put attribute value in double quotes .

Please have a look:: https://github.com/xmlunit/xmlunit/issues/110

Comment: I think that by "general programming concept" you mean the escape convention used in the family of languages derived from C (that is, use of backslashes). That's a widespread convention but it's by no means universal or general.

Answer (score 1):

This is what i use for this specific condition of single and/or double quotes.
Try this and check with the text you need to verify.

```
    if (!TextString.contains("'")) {
        XPath = "//*[contains(text(), \"" + TextString + "\")]" + " | " + "//*[contains(normalize-space(), \"" + TextString + "\")]";
    } else if (!Label.contains("\"")) {
        XPath = "//*[contains(text(), '" + TextString + "')]" + " | " + "//*[contains(normalize-space(), '" + TextString + "')]";
    } else {
        XPath = "//*[contains(text()," + "concat('" + TextString.replace("'", "',\"'\",'") + "'))]" + " | " + "//*[contains(normalize-space()," + "concat('" + TextString.replace("'", "',\"'\",'") + "'))]";
    }
```